# Downsize series containing boolean data with resample

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I have a large time series dataframe containing numerical and boolean data in separate columns. I am trying to downsample the data from 1-min interval to 15-min interval. The boolean columns are system statuses and I am struggling with how to downsample them and still retain any faults. Currently, my resample uses `last` thus would overlook any system faults that occur on any row but the last.

What I would like it to do: if 'fault' occurs on any row during the 15-min series, then the resulting timestamp after the resample would read 'fault' else would read 'ok'.

I know the solution reside in `how=''` of resample, but because I am new to numpy and pandas I can't figure out what to use.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Reads .csv, combines Date and Time columns into Timestamp, sets Timestamp as index
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates = {'Timestamp' : ['Date', 'Time']}, index_col = 'Timestamp')

# Fixing any incomplete data and interpolating any numerical gaps 
index = pd.date_range(freq='1min', start=df.first_valid_index(), end=df.last_valid_index())
df_clean = df.reindex(set(df.index).union(index))
for col in df_clean:
    df_clean[col] = df_clean[col].interpolate('time').ix[index]

# Downsampling numerical data 
df_avg = df_clean.resample('15min', how='mean')

# Downsampling boolean data separately 
df_avg['alarm1']=df_clean['alarm1'].resample('15min', how='last')

# Fix for missing index name
df_avg.index.name = 'Timestamp'

# Adding date and time columns back to dataframe
df_avg.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df_avg['Date'] = df_avg['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
df_avg['Time'] = df_avg['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

# Write new .csv 
df_avg[['Date','Time','A','B','C','alarm1']].to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docstring says `how` should be a string, but in fact it can also be a callable.

If the 'alarm1' column is boolean, you can use `how=any` (or `how=np.any`).  `any` will logically `or` the values in each time bin, so if any value in the bin is True, the value in the downsampled series will be True.

Here's an example.

First, set the random seed and create a series of boolean values.

```
In [101]: np.random.seed(123456)

In [102]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=25, freq='1min')

In [103]: ts = pd.Series(np.random.rand(len(rng)) > 0.85, index=rng)

In [104]: ts
Out[104]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00    False
2011-01-01 00:01:00     True
2011-01-01 00:02:00    False
2011-01-01 00:03:00     True
2011-01-01 00:04:00    False
2011-01-01 00:05:00    False
2011-01-01 00:06:00    False
2011-01-01 00:07:00    False
2011-01-01 00:08:00    False
2011-01-01 00:09:00    False
2011-01-01 00:10:00    False
2011-01-01 00:11:00    False
2011-01-01 00:12:00    False
2011-01-01 00:13:00     True
2011-01-01 00:14:00    False
2011-01-01 00:15:00    False
2011-01-01 00:16:00    False
2011-01-01 00:17:00    False
2011-01-01 00:18:00    False
2011-01-01 00:19:00    False
2011-01-01 00:20:00     True
2011-01-01 00:21:00    False
2011-01-01 00:22:00    False
2011-01-01 00:23:00    False
2011-01-01 00:24:00    False
Freq: T, dtype: bool
```

Use `resample` to convert to 5 minute frequency.  Use `how=np.any` to logically `or` the values in the time bin.

```
In [105]: ds = ts.resample('5min', how=np.any)

In [106]: ds
Out[106]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00     True
2011-01-01 00:05:00    False
2011-01-01 00:10:00     True
2011-01-01 00:15:00    False
2011-01-01 00:20:00     True
Freq: 5T, dtype: bool
```

You could also sum the values, which will give you the number of alarms in each time bin:

```
In [107]: ts.resample('5min', how=sum)
Out[107]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00    2
2011-01-01 00:05:00    0
2011-01-01 00:10:00    1
2011-01-01 00:15:00    0
2011-01-01 00:20:00    1
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

---

Update:

If, as mentioned in a comment, the `alarm1` column contains the strings `'YES'` and `'NO'`, there are several ways you can handle it.  For example, you could simply convert the values to boolean (e.g. `tsbool = ts == 'YES'`) and use the above technique.

Or, you could write a custom aggregation function, such as

```
def func(faults):
    return 'YES' if np.any(faults == 'YES') else 'NO'
```

and give it as the `how` argument of `resample`.  Here's an example.

First, create a series containing the strings 'YES' and 'NO'.

```
In [60]: rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=25, freq='1min')

In [61]: yn = np.array(['NO', 'YES'])

In [62]: ts = pd.Series(yn[(np.random.rand(len(rng)) > 0.85).astype(int)], index=rng)

In [63]: ts
Out[63]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:01:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:02:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:03:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:04:00    YES
2011-01-01 00:05:00    YES
2011-01-01 00:06:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:07:00    YES
2011-01-01 00:08:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:09:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:10:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:11:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:12:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:13:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:14:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:15:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:16:00    YES
2011-01-01 00:17:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:18:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:19:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:20:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:21:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:22:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:23:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:24:00     NO
Freq: T, dtype: object
```

Define the function that reduces an array of 'YES' and 'NO' strings to single string.

```
In [64]: def func(alarms):
   ....:     return 'YES' if np.any(alarms == 'YES') else 'NO'
   ....:
```

Use the function to resample `ts`.

```
In [65]: ds = ts.resample('5min', how=func)

In [66]: ds
Out[66]: 
2011-01-01 00:00:00    YES
2011-01-01 00:05:00    YES
2011-01-01 00:10:00     NO
2011-01-01 00:15:00    YES
2011-01-01 00:20:00     NO
Freq: 5T, dtype: object
```

Comment: Looks like I misspoke. My fault column contains YES/NO data, which python doesn't seem to consider as boolean. Is there a way to parse my fault column with y/n instead of t/f?

Comment: I defined a new function and it works great! Thank you!

Comment: I have a large dataframe and found that it was a lot faster to use 'sum' with an inequality function: `df.resample('15min', how='sum') >= 1`